# Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

You'll have to go easy on me.. very new to React Native

I have this piece of code, pretty simple:

```
export default class signup extends Component {

      constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          loaded: true,
          email: '',
          password: ''
        };
      }

      signup(){

        this.setState({
          loaded: false
        });




    firebaseApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(function() {

      this.props.navigator.push({
          component: Login
        });

    }, function(error) {
      // An error happened.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log("ERROR WITH SIGNIN")
      console.log( errorMessage )
    });




      }

      goToLogin(){
        this.props.navigator.push({
          component: Login
        });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Header text="Signup" loaded={this.state.loaded} />
            <View style={styles.body}>

              <TextInput
                style={styles.textinput}
                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email: text})}
                value={this.state.email}
                placeholder={"Email Address"}
              />
              <TextInput
                style={styles.textinput}
                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}
                value={this.state.password}
                secureTextEntry={true}
                placeholder={"Password"}
              />
              <Button 
                text="Signup" 
                onpress={this.signup.bind(this)} 
                button_styles={styles.primary_button} 
                button_text_styles={styles.primary_button_text} />

              <Button 
                text="Got an Account?" 
                onpress={this.goToLogin.bind(this)} 
                button_styles={styles.transparent_button} 
                button_text_styles={styles.transparent_button_text} />
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('signup', () => signup);
```

What I do not understand is if I click the "Go to login" button it runs the function perfectly and goes to the Login page

```
 goToLogin(){
    this.props.navigator.push({
      component: Login
    });
  }
```

However when I click the signup button, it throws the error

> Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

I figured I could just put the same block of code for it to run :

```
 this.props.navigator.push({
          component: Login
        });
```

However it causes an error. I am a little confused why this would be happening as it works perfectly in the other function.. I am sure this is just me and my lack of understanding of react native..
Thanks guys!

Comment: Should'nt the **onpress** event you are using in button be like **onPress**. It could be the cause of your problem

Answer (score 2):

You need to use bind or arrow functions

```
firebaseApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(function() {

  this.props.navigator.push({
      component: Login
    });

}.bind(this), function(error) {
  // An error happened.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  console.log("ERROR WITH SIGNIN")
  console.log( errorMessage )
});
```

> OR

```
firebaseApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(() => {

  this.props.navigator.push({
      component: Login
    });

}, function(error) {
  // An error happened.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  console.log("ERROR WITH SIGNIN")
  console.log( errorMessage )
});
```